# Thread Priority with order (1,2,3,...n)

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

In .NET framework, I know that a thread can be assigned any one of the following priority values:

```
Highest
AboveNormal
Normal
BelowNormal
Lowest
```

But what if 2 threads in same priority and I want them to be start in an order like
1,2,3...n. Greater number will have lower start order.

Any suggestion?
For example:

```
new Thread(() => OrderFactory.Match(GetOrders()[1]), order: 3).Start();
new Thread(() => OrderFactory.Match(GetOrders()[2]), order: 2).Start(); => start second
new Thread(() => OrderFactory.Match(GetOrders()[3]), order: 4).Start();
new Thread(() => OrderFactory.Match(GetOrders()[4]), order: 5).Start();
new Thread(() => OrderFactory.Match(GetOrders()[5]), order: 1).Start(); => start first
```

I know that there is plenty of topic out there, but somehow I can't find the right one...

Comment: Multi-threading is a complicated concept. I would advise you to get some information about the related issues before you start mashing up code - a great start would be this free e-book: http://www.albahari.com/threading/ It's very easy to get unexpected results when you don't understand what guarantees are broken when you're no longer running code in just one thread. One of those broken guarantees is the order of execution, which you've just found out :) And do not mess with thread/process priorities. It's not what you think it is.

Comment: I just want to say that your comment is really really helpful. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK there is no mechanism that you can control the start up for the `Thread` but is worth asking that why you want this,

> I want them to be start in an order like 1,2,3...n. Greater number will have lower start order

because you use `Thread` when you do not care about things to happen in a particular order.

Is it that you want particular part to get synchronized?

After assigning the priority too it's not a guarantee when windows will execute a particular thread, Windows will only decide the sequence.
If you really want, that 1 starts before 2 then either `Start` them in order and have a little pause b/w starts of thread or let thread 1 start thread 2.......

Comment: Thanks, I understand :) I will figure more and update the information here later.